# Can the preprocessor expand Objective-C macros to multiple lines?

Tags: objective-c, macros

Having this macro:

```
#define RUN_ON_MAIN_THREAD(block) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
```

and this usage of it:

```
RUN_ON_MAIN_THREAD(^{
    NSLog(@"first line");

    NSLog(@"second line");
});
```

it expands to:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ NSLog(@"first line"); NSLog(@"seconds line"); });
```

which makes it impossible to have a working breakpoint on the line with `NSLog(@"second line");`.

Is there any way to make it expand to:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSLog(@"first line");

    NSLog(@"seconds line");
});
```

?

Comment: I would recommend to stop using macros to make your code slightly shorter and you won't have this problem. Why don't you just create a global function instead?

Comment: please check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9435889/write-macros-for-gcd-calls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a macro with multiple lines of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374107/how-to-create-a-macro-with-multiple-lines-of-code)

Comment: @dmitryguzeev, That's about *defining* the macro on multiple lines.

Comment: @Sulthan, Do you have a link for me please?

Comment: I guess the debugger should be capable of going through macro which is defined this way?

Comment: Well, it doesn't. That's why I posted this question.

Comment: Just define a global function `void RUN_ON_MAIN_THREAD(dispatch_block_t block) { dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), block); }` Called with the same syntax but without the macro mess. Second answer in the linked question above https://stackoverflow.com/a/9435935/669586

Comment: @Sulthan, Sorry, I completely missed that comment. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I would suggest using inline function instead of macro in your's case.

Comment: Doesn't sound like the preprocessor makes any particular guarantees about whitespace as long as the semantics are not changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796947/spaces-inserted-by-the-c-preprocessor/37797110#37797110

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can define multi-line macros (use `\` at the end of a line), and macros can expand into multiple lines (although technically unnecessary as C/Obj-C ignores most whitespace).

But the real answer is: don't do this

This global function will (a) produce the equivalent source code as your macro and (b) will actually generate less machine code. (Your macro generates that same dispatch calls over and over, while this function encapsulates them in a single code block.)

```
// Shorthand for asynchronously dispatching a block to execute on the main thread
void DispatchOnMain( dispatch_block_t block )
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),block);
}
```

Your code would then look like this:

```
DispatchOnMain(^{
    NSLog(@"first line");

    NSLog(@"second line");
});
```

Comment: This is about expanding a macro on multiple lines, not defining a macro on multiple lines.

Comment: Yes, and I answered both, and pointed out this wasn't an optimal solution.

Comment: It's very useful advice, but it doesn't answer my question at all, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530879/can-the-preprocessor-expand-objective-c-macros-to-multiple-lines/54561049?noredirect=1#comment95884134_54530879) answers it.